So...to structure

His talent in music was so impressive that none could deny him an opportunity.

His talent in music was so impressive to deny him an opportunity.


While I think #1 is grammatical, I am sure about the second one.
Please give your views.

eg, in CD: so something as to be something The word itself is so rare as to be almost obsolete. // Collins < 13. adverb
You can use so...that and so...as to [to] emphasize the degree of something by mentioning the result or consequence of it....
• The deal seems so attractive it would be ridiculous to say no.
• Frescoes are so familiar a feature of Italian churches that it is easy to take them for granted.
• He's not so daft as to listen to rumours. >

"He's not so daft as to listen to rumours." I got it. Thank you for this example, Edwin Ashworth.

The second one is not only ungrammatical, but illogical.

His talent for music was so impressive as to...

but if you end it with deny him an opportunity, it has the opposite meaning to sentence 1. You need to say something like provide him with many opportunities.

I understood. Thank you, Kate Bunting.

@Suresh Grammatically, the "so" that modifies "impressive" can license finite clauses (like the that clause in 1.) but it cannot license non-finite clauses like the one in 2.

Thank you for this post, BillJ. It is very helpful.
